# Conflicting Information on PyTorch 2.1.1 Compatibility with CUDA Versions: 12.3 vs 12.1

Tags: pytorch

I'm currently using PyTorch version 2.1.1. I have a question about its compatibility with CUDA versions. I've been reading opinions on online forums and discussion boards about whether PyTorch 2.1.1 or the current nightly builds can work with CUDA version 12.3 or if it's only compatible, with CUDA versions 12.1.

- Can anyone confirm if PyTorch 2.1.1 or the nightly builds can effectively run on CUDA version 12.3?

If anyone has experience or knows of any documentation that can clarify this question it would be really helpful and greatly appreciated.

I haven't tried upgrading to CUDA 12.3 yet in case it might not work, and I would have to go back to 12.1 again.

Comment: I can't get it done. I run CUDA 12.3, but Pytoch won't accept the GPU.